# Graphics Device initialization failed for : d3d, sw Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found

Tags: java

I'm coding in eclipse and was following this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xTSxNw7UHng tutorial. I did everything the video said even the inclusion of

```
  exports WindowTest;
```

I don't know why I keep getting this error. Could I please get assistance in fixing this problem

Current Code:

```
package WindowTest;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
public class Main extends Application{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage s)
    {
        s.setWidth(800);
        s.setHeight(600);
        s.show();
    }
    public static void main(String passes[])
    {
        launch(passes);
    }

}
```

and

```
module WindowTest {
    requires javafx.base;
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.media;
    requires javafx.swing;
    requires javafx.swt;
    requires javafx.web;
    exports WindowTest;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this will be useful? [How to solve the “Graphics Device initialization failed for : d3d, sw” Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55561986/how-to-solve-the-graphics-device-initialization-failed-for-d3d-sw-problem)

Comment: @Scratte I've already tried everything I could with [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55561986/how-to-solve-the-graphics-device-initialization-failed-for-d3d-sw-problem) None of it worked.

Comment: I've never used the javafx before. I just downloaded the SDK, unzipped it. Made sure the module path was set to the lib folder and ran it. When I renamed the bin folder, I got your exact error. I did not go through all the posts except I noticed one post pointing our the bin folder name.