# Having Problems Installing JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, openjfx

Recently tried to install JavaFX with IntelliJ and followed each step. I tried to Run the "Main" Class and it gave me the following errors:

```
C:\Users\janl\.jdks\openjdk-15.0.1\bin\java.exe --module-path \Users\janl\OneDrive\Desktop\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics --add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=58993:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\janl\IdeaProjects\FX\out\production\FX;C:\Users\janl\OneDrive\Desktop\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib\src.zip;C:\Users\janl\OneDrive\Desktop\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib\javafx-swt.jar;C:\Users\janl\OneDrive\Desktop\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib\javafx.web.jar;C:\Users\janl\OneDrive\Desktop\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib\javafx.base.jar;C:\Users\janl\OneDrive\Desktop\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib\javafx.fxml.jar;C:\Users\janl\OneDrive\Desktop\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib\javafx.media.jar;C:\Users\janl\OneDrive\Desktop\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib\javafx.swing.jar;C:\Users\janl\OneDrive\Desktop\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib\javafx.controls.jar;C:\Users\janl\OneDrive\Desktop\javafx-sdk-15.0.1\lib\javafx.graphics.jar sample.Main
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:244)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:261)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1071)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:273)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    ... 5 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be?
That'd be very much appreciated!

Comment: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that may be of help. [How to solve the "Graphics Device initialization failed for : d3d, sw" Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55561986/how-to-solve-the-graphics-device-initialization-failed-for-d3d-sw-problem). The person had a similar problem to yours.