# Javafx setup issues

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, processing

I'm not really sure what to do with these errors. I'm trying to use processing in Eclipse with javafx, and I don't remember it being this involved a few years ago. When I try to run my java app without javafx I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/scene/transform/Transform
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3373)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3578)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2271)
at processing.core.PApplet.makeGraphics(PApplet.java:2265)
at processing.core.PApplet.createPrimaryGraphics(PApplet.java:2345)
at processing.core.PApplet.initSurface(PApplet.java:10983)
at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10922)
at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10657)
at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10639)
at Exercise2.DrawThisInput.main(DrawThisInput.java:102)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.scene.transform.Transform
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
... 11 more
```

When I run it with javafx.base, controls, fxml, graphics,media, swing, web, and swt jars I get this error:

```
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:283)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:253)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:263)
at com.sun.javafx.perf.PerformanceTracker.logEvent(PerformanceTracker.java:100)
at javafx.scene.Node.<clinit>(Node.java:417)
at processing.javafx.PGraphicsFX2D$FontCache.<init>(PGraphicsFX2D.java:1391)
at processing.javafx.PGraphicsFX2D.<init>(PGraphicsFX2D.java:1294)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at processing.core.PApplet.makeGraphics(PApplet.java:2266)
at processing.core.PApplet.createPrimaryGraphics(PApplet.java:2345)
at processing.core.PApplet.initSurface(PApplet.java:10983)
at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10922)
at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10657)
at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10639)
at Exercise2.DrawThisInput.main(DrawThisInput.java:102)


Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:95)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)


java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at processing.javafx.PGraphicsFX2D$FontCache.<init>(PGraphicsFX2D.java:1391)
at processing.javafx.PGraphicsFX2D.<init>(PGraphicsFX2D.java:1294)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
at processing.core.PApplet.makeGraphics(PApplet.java:2266)
at processing.core.PApplet.createPrimaryGraphics(PApplet.java:2345)
at processing.core.PApplet.initSurface(PApplet.java:10983)
at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10922)
at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10657)
at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10639)
at Exercise2.DrawThisInput.main(DrawThisInput.java:102)


Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:275)
at com.sun.javafx.perf.PerformanceTracker.logEvent(PerformanceTracker.java:100)
at javafx.scene.Node.<clinit>(Node.java:417)
... 14 more



java.lang.RuntimeException
at processing.core.PApplet.makeGraphics(PApplet.java:2299)
at processing.core.PApplet.createPrimaryGraphics(PApplet.java:2345)
at processing.core.PApplet.initSurface(PApplet.java:10983)
at processing.core.PApplet.runSketch(PApplet.java:10922)
at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10657)
at processing.core.PApplet.main(PApplet.java:10639)
at Exercise2.DrawThisInput.main(DrawThisInput.java:102)
```

Is this the result of using too recent a version of javafx? The code I'm building off of is fairly old, or is this something else?

Comment: which version of jdk did you use?

Comment: @jvatechs how can I check that? At this point I'm not sure if I ended up going back to an older version to try and figure out if there were compatibility issues. If that's the same as Java Control Panel, it says 1.8.0, but for any of my jar files I've been bouncing back and forth on versions

Comment: try the first answer from the link -> [How to solve the "Graphics Device initialization failed for : d3d, sw" Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55561986/how-to-solve-the-graphics-device-initialization-failed-for-d3d-sw-problem)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve the "Graphics Device initialization failed for : d3d, sw" Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55561986/how-to-solve-the-graphics-device-initialization-failed-for-d3d-sw-problem)

Comment: Official instructions for setting up various IDEs (including Eclipse) to build and run JavaFX applications are at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/. Did you follow those?